# In DialogFragment called by two different activities, how do you cast back to the calling activity for this case?

Tags: android, android-activity, casting, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` successfully working with my `MainActivity`. It calls the activity's `doPositiveClick()` method with

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).doPositiveClick()
```

So far so good, but now I want to re-use the same `DialogFragment` with `SecondActivity`. I have experimented with the syntax of the above line but I still have not found a way of replacing `MainActivity` with something that could denote `MainActivity` or `SecondActivity` depending on which called the `DialogFragment`. I have had both activities implementing an interface with `doPositiveClick()` but still I have not hit upon the right syntax to satisfy my requirement.

Let me be clear: I am asking a yes or no question. Can I adjust the above line, so I do not have to involve a `Listener` on an interface? Is yes, how? If no, fair enough.

Comment: I would say using an interface is the best way. The only other way I can think of is using `instanceof`and an if statement. However, implementing an interface in both activities sounds reasonable. Any reason against it?

Comment: My question is about casting. I wish to know if there is a way to cast appropriately in this situation, thus producing a much more efficient implementation rather than having to bring in a whole new interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface is the best practice for communicate with the fragment to activity ( **not opposite** ). 
You can just make a parent activity implement your interface and make your mainactivity and secondactivity child. So you dont need to implement. You can just override the methods. So which activity make the fragment, that activity override method will trigger when fragment calls. I hope i understand your problem truly and answering truly. Any question please comment it. So i can answer via comment and also i can edit my answer.

**Update**: Simply yes :) In your fragment onAttach method you can control instance of the which activity create this fragment. I hope this will make you satisfied.

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof MainActivity) ...
        if (activity instanceof SecondActivity) ...
    }
```

Comment: I wish to know if it is possible to produce a working solution by appropriate casting in the given line (a 'yes' or 'no' answer). My question is more to do with casting than a solution to this particular problem. However I agree with you that making MainActivity and SecondActivity children of ParentActivity in the sway you suggest means that we could just change `MainActivity`to `ParentActivity` in the given line. So unless someone suggests a cast that works without bringing in a new class or interface, I will be accepting your answer.

Comment: I want to answer like yes, no but i have to sure what you asking truly. But after your comment so i can answer like way you want. **Yes** :) Check answer. It's updated.